# How can I set first option selected on ng-select angular 8?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am generating multiple dropdowns from a nested array. I wanted to first option selected for all dropdowns. Here is my code on html

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let siz of product.attributes">
     <ng-select autocomplete="attributes" formControlName="attributes" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && val.get('attributes').errors }" class="mt-2" bindValue="{{ siz }}" bindLabel="{{ siz }}" [items]="siz.value" placeholder="Select {{ siz.name }}" (change)="sizeChange($event, siz.name)"></ng-select>
</ng-container>
```

Other everything working fine, I just need to first option selected by default.

Here is attributes array 
[image]

Comment: Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/angular)

Comment: I am using formBuilder for data,

Answer (score 1):

Get the value before everything in onInit

```
selected = product.attributes.map(x => x.value.map(y => y)[0])[0];
```

Use method 1 while initializing your form

**Method 1:**

```js
//fb is formbuilder
this.form = fb.group({
   attributes: [selected, Vaidators.required] // selected is the default value
});
```

**Method 2:**
After form is initialized

```
this.form.controls['attributes'].setValue(selected);
```

.ts file

```html
<ng-select formControlName="attributes">
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using formBuilder for values. how to do with form builde ?

Comment: Edited the answer per requirement